# What does "def loop: Boolean = loop" do in Scala

Tags: java, scala, boolean, function

A detailed information on what does the above statement (the one enclosed in quotes) does in Scala would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why dont you check it by yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a recursive method that just calls itself. It creates an infinite loop.

Comment: What would be the difference when I write the following two statements?
def x1=loop
AND
val x2=loop

Comment: Sounds like you're doing the Coursera course. The video lectures explain this. Both would call loop, and hence recurse infinitely.

Comment: I am not doing any course. I was trying to learn the language myself. I am completely new to this language.
Thanks for your help :)